# Simulate click on an element when using element.eventlistener in jest + enzyme set up

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme, testcase

I have a component lets say `<MyComponent>`. I have a `<button>Click me</button>` in the component which has a event listener on click added in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    const btn = document.getElementById('button');
    if (btn) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', onButtonClicked, false);
    }
    return function cleanupListener() {
      if (btn) btn.removeEventListener('click', onButtonClicked);
    };
  }, []);
```

I need to simulate click on that button in test case using jest + enzyme.
Went through one of the answer which had a solution like this but it didn't work

```
beforeEach(() => {
  const map = {};
  const namedByRefComponent = Wrapper.find("button");
  const namedByRefDomNode = namedByRefComponent.getDOMNode();
  const namedByRefDomNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(namedByRefComponent);
  namedByRefDomNode.addEventListener = jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementation((event, cb) => {
      map[event] = cb;
    });
});
```

Can someone help me out with new solution or complete the above solution because I am not able to figure it out

Thanks in advance